# Azure Logic App suddenly returns 202 instead of 200

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I've been developing an Azure Logic App for the past two days, here and there adding different connectors and functionality. After adding a SQL Server action, calling the Logic App endpoint results in a Status 202 instead of the app running and returning a Status 200.

I can't find how to fix this nor why it happened.

**Background**:

- TRIGGER: HTTP request
- TRIGGER_CONDITIONS: I check to see if certain headers are present
- ACTIONS: Many including Azure Storage, Azure SQL, Outlook, O365Users, etc.
- RESPONSE: HTTP response

**Tried**:

- Removing the recently added SQL Server action: No change
- Removing the latest Trigger Condition: No change
- Regenerating the SAS tokenized URL: No change

**Observations**:

- There has been no `Run History` since the issue happened
- But the Status 202 runs show in `Trigger History`

--
**EDIT 1**:

- Looks like its the Trigger Conditions.

  - If I remove all of them, the request triggers the app
- How then do I check for request headers?
- I had `@empty(triggerOutputs()['headers']['<header name>'])`

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I needed to negate the `empty()` check...

- `@not(empty(triggerOutputs()['headers']['genre']))`